# How to call function before request redirects

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

I am using Kohana3. Before redirecting page to the new URL, I want to perform some processing. I tried to use **after** method of the controller class, but **after** method of Controller does not execute if request is redirected. Also I tried to use register_shutdown_function, but still its not called when request redirects to other page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own controller's method `redirect($url, $code)` and use it for redirects instead of `$this->request->redirect()`:

```
// basic controller

protected function _redirect($url, $code=302)
{
   $this->_shutdown();
   $this->request->redirect($url, $code);
}

protected function _shutdown()
{
   // log queries, stats etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean when using this?

```
$this->request->redirect('/somewhere')
```

If so, could you call your function before that line?

If you are looking for something to run when the object is de-initialised, try magic  method [`__destruct()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)...

```
public function __destuct() {
   // Something
}
```

Comment: @Alex: The requirement is basically to log all the database queries being executed. So I have declared a function which need to be called at the end of each request. It works perfectly, but fails whenever page gets redirected.

Comment: @Asi Mulla You should probably extend the `Db` module, and use `Kohana::log()` for your logging requirements.

Comment: @alex: Here if I extend Db class, then Db class doesn't have any execute method inside. So is it possible to log query on successful execution? How can I do that?

Comment: @Asi Mulla You should vote my answer up too :) Which DB queries are you using? Raw SQL, Query builder or ORM? You can get the last query with `Database::instance()->last_query`.

Comment: @Adex: 1 Vote for you. I m using Query builder mostly DB::query,DB::INSERT,DB::UPDATE and DB::DELETE. Now tell me which class I need to extend and which method to override to fetch query?